# mips assembly octal to decimal

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

i have a task where i need to turn octal numbers in the data to their right decimal counterpart.
the numbers in the data are in octal and i need to turn then to decimal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POmyk.png).

i tried to make loop that suppurate the 10' bit like 3 in 35.

for example for the number 35 i need that in the end ,in the register will be 29d.
also can i do it in byte or i need to change it to ascii ?

Comment: You need to divide by 10, so the quotient is the 3 and the remainder is the 5. Then you can put the octal together by shifting the quotient by 3 bits which is the same as multiplying by 8.

Comment: thank you so much, will it work for every octal number ?

Comment: Every 2 digit octal number.

Comment: The numbers are written in the source in decimal, not octal.  Once the assembler is done, they'll be in binary.  If you want to recover their decimal digits, divide by 10 and look at the quotient and remainder.  You can then reinterpret those digits as octal, to get a binary integer with the value `3*8 + 5`.  Your (assignment's) way of describing it is backwards, I guess thinking in terms of correcting a mistake in the asm source of writing integer literals that were intended as octal, but forgetting to tell the assembler about that.  (Like `0o35` might work in some assemblers.)

Comment: If you want to see the output on the screen, you'll need to convert to ASCII before printing.